# How to iterate over a 1D tensor with indicies?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to iterate over a tensor and get the index of each element.

For example...

```
tensor = tf.constant([1,2,3])

for idx, elem in enumerate(tensor):
    print(idx, elem)
```

desired output:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
```

Comment: What is `tf.__version__`? 1 or 2?

Comment: What's wrong with the current output?

Comment: @cs95 tf 1.11.0 Should i upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pair a 1D tensor with indices, use `tf.stack` and `tf.range` (TF 1.x and 2.0 compatible):

```
tf.stack([tf.range(tf.shape(tensor)[0]), tensor], axis=1)
# <tf.Tensor 'stack:0' shape=(3, 2) dtype=int32>
```

Whatever you need to do, you can probably do without having to actually iterate over the tenor.

Comment: I'm getting an error TypeError: object of type 'Tensor' has no len()

Answer (score 0):

Enable eager execution

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
tensor = tf.constant([1,2,3])
for idx, elem in enumerate(tensor):
    tf.print(idx, elem)

0 1
1 2
2 3
```

Comment: i can't do eager execution for the purposes of my problem